# How to build listview inside FragmentTabHost inside scrollview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

I want to build a page that have a Scrollview which include a FragmentTabHost, and inside the FragmentTabHost I have 3 tabs that each tab contains fragment with listview.

example:

**main_activity**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Relative1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Relative1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Relative2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ImageButton1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/listview1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</ListView>
```

I know that it's not recommended to put listview inside scrollview and the best way is to add header to the list view, but how it's possible with the FragmentTabHost?

What is the recommended way to build this page?

Comment: just think ... your layout has no sens ... if scrollview height/width match parent and tab host's height/width inside it match parent the scrollview is redundant (height/width - depends if scrollview is horizontal or vertical)

Comment: you are right, it was an abortive attempt to stretch the listview,  but this is not the point, I want to know what is the recommended structure to build this page, perhaps without insert listview inside scrollview. the problem here is the FragmentTabHost.